# "Unable to find dependency..." when building smart device CAB project in VS2008

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-mobile-6.5

I'm trying to get a Setup project to build, and it does but with a Warning saying: 
Unable to find dependency 'mscorlib' (Signature='969DB8053D3322AC' Version='2.0.0.0') of assembly 'Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Samples.Location.dll'
The solution also contains some C# projects and a .NET assemblie: Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Samples.Location.dll
does anyone know why I get these messages and how to configure my Setup to get rid of them ?

Comment: Any of your projects has a reference to this assembly and the setup project is unable to find it. Locate the reference and check the assembly exists and has the correct version. You should post a scren shot of the solution explorer with references expanded